# JavaScript Function is always returning 0

Tags: javascript, html

This function looks right to me but when I run it, all I get back is `0` in the console even when the value is `"Extra Cheese"`. Below is a portion of my code, so `runningTotal` and `text1` are defined elsewhere, but this is the part that isn't working :

```
function getCheese(runningTotal,text1) {
    var cheeseTotal = 0;
    var selectedCheese = [];
    var cheeseArray = document.getElementsByClassName("cheese");
    for (var m = 0; m < cheeseArray.length; m++) {
        if (cheeseArray[m].checked) {
            selectedCheese.push(cheeseArray[m].value);
            console.log("selected cheese item: ("+cheeseArray[m].value+")");
            text1 = text1+cheeseArray[m].value+"<br>";
        }
    }
    if (selectedCheese === "Extra Cheese") {
        cheeseTotal = 3;
    } 
    else if (selectedCheese === "No Cheese") {
        cheeseTotal = 0;
    }
    else if (selectedCheese === "Regular") {
        selectedCheese = 0;
    }
    runningTotal = (runningTotal + cheeseTotal);
    console.log(cheeseTotal);
    document.getElementById("showText").innerHTML=text1;
    document.getElementById("totalPrice").innerHTML = "</h3>Total: <strong>$"+runningTotal+".00"+"</strong></h3>";
};
```

Comment: `selectedCheese` looks like an `array` and you are comparing an array to string for `"Extra Cheese"/"No Cheese"/"Regular"`. Would that work ???

Comment: Which variable do you have in mind?

Comment: As Panther points you, you are comparing type and value of an array against a string. None of your if statements are going to be true because of this.

Comment: The variable totalCheese

Comment: The array is populated with the string values "Regular","No Cheese", and "Extra Cheese"

Comment: Yeah and an array does not equal a string..... Why is an an array when it seems like they can only select one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i came up with and it worked, thank you all for the help and pointers.

```
function getCheese(runningTotal,text1) {
        var cheeseTotal = 0;
        var cheeseArray = document.getElementsByClassName("cheese");
        for (var m = 0; m < cheeseArray.length; m++) {
            if (cheeseArray[m].checked) {
                var selectedCheese=(cheeseArray[m].value);
                text1 = text1+selectedCheese+"<br>";
            }
        }
        if (selectedCheese === "Extra Cheese") {
            runningTotal = runningTotal + 3;
        } 
        else
        { cheeseTotal = 0; 
    }

        runningTotal = (runningTotal + cheeseTotal);
        document.getElementById("showText").innerHTML=text1;
        document.getElementById("totalPrice").innerHTML = "</h3>Total: <strong>$"+runningTotal+".00"+"</strong></h3>";
        getCrust(runningTotal,text1);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You're checking whether an array `===` a string, which is going to return false no matter what you do. Since you declare the `cheseTotal = 0` at the very top, it's going to check all your conditionals, return false on all of them, and do nothing. So when you `console.log(cheeseTotal)`, it is going to return the value you declared at the very top.

What you want is to see if an array `includes` a string:

```
   if (selectedCheese.includes("Extra Cheese")) {
        cheeseTotal = 3;
    } else if...
```

Here's some more information about the method:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: or more cross-browser compatibility:
`if (selectedCheese.indexOf("Extra Cheese")) {
        cheeseTotal = 3;
    } else if...`

Comment: Curious, does that actually work? If the "Extra Cheese" doesn't exist it returns `-1`, which seems to return true: https://codepen.io/foozie3moons/pen/OxOBXj

Comment: function getCheese(runningTotal,text1) {  
 var cheeseTotal = 0;
 var cheeseArray = document.getElementsByClassName("cheese");
 for (var i = 0; i < cheeseArray.length; i++) {
  if (cheeseArray[i].checked) {
   var selectedSize = cheeseArray[i].value;
   text1 = text1+selectedCheese+"<br>";
  }
 }

Comment: I can barely read that code. In the future use backticks to surround your code. Without seeing your HTML/other supporting code it makes it difficult to tell whether or not that code will do what you intend. It looks like valid javascript to me.

However, as Andrew points out, `selectedCheese` may not even need to be an array. If you have three radio buttons, and are checking which one is checked, you can just have one value for `seletedCheese` instead of an array. Then your previous conditionals should return the proper values.

Comment: @Matthew. You are right I forgot to test it the indexOf value. It should be 'if (selectedCheese.indexOf("Extra Cheese")!==-1) { cheeseTotal = 3; } else if...'

Answer (score 0):

I found a few things wrong with your code. for starters your if clauses should be in the for loop as well. You are using an unneeded second array (`selectedCheese`). Second you can add a total up by using the `+=` operator, which makes your `runningtotal` not needed either. I was not sure what the parameters for the function are (or why they are needed) I would suggest re-look at that as it seems like you can remove them.

Below is a running snippet of my solution for your issue.

```js
function getCheese(runningTotal, text1) {
  var cheeseTotal = 0;
  var selectedCheese = [];
  var cheeseArray = document.getElementsByClassName("cheese");
  for (var m = 0; m < cheeseArray.length; m++) {
    if (cheeseArray[m].checked) {
      var cheeseVal = cheeseArray[m].value;
      console.log("selected cheese item: (" + cheeseVal + ")");
      if (cheeseVal === "Extra Cheese") {
        cheeseTotal += 3;
      } else if (cheeseVal === "No Cheese") {
        cheeseTotal += 0;
      } else if (cheeseVal === "Regular") {
        cheeseTotal += 0;
      }
      text1 = text1 + "<br>" + cheeseVal ;
    }
  }
  console.log(cheeseTotal);
  document.getElementById("showText").innerHTML = text1;
  document.getElementById("totalPrice").innerHTML = "</h3>Total: <strong>$" + cheeseTotal + ".00" + "</strong></h3>";
};
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="cheese" value="Extra Cheese">Extra Cheese</input>
<input type="checkbox" class="cheese" value="No Cheese">No Cheese</input>
<input type="checkbox" class="cheese" value="Regular">Regular</input>
<button onclick="getCheese(0, 'Cheeses')"> submit </button>

<div id="showText"></div>
<div id="totalPrice"></div>
```

Comment: The running total is to keep track of the total price of the Pizza, definitely my fault for not explaining the functionality of the entire script. The website is a Pizza ordering website, this is one of many thing you can add to the pizza.

Comment: The `cheeseTotal` var is now your `runningtotal`. Does the above example make sense to you? Let me know if it doesn't make sense